# Copying and resetting memory without interruption between them

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, texas-instruments

I'm trying to copy my input trigger mask before start reading it and setting the outputs, but I suspect that maybe the input interrupt sometimes happens between these two lines below so I missing out the last change, because when changing the input fast, sometimes the output stays on its previous state.

```
trigger_mask_t tmask = gpio_trigger_mask;
gpio_trigger_mask.bits = 0;

if (!tmask.bits)
    // reading the inputs and setting the outputs here.
```

My interrupt function:

```
void gpioCbFxn(PIN_Handle handle, PIN_Id pinId)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(GPIO_tab); i++)
    {
        if (pinId == GPIO_tab[i])
        {
            gpio_trigger_mask.bits |= (1 << i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My trigger mask struct:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t IN1 : 1,
             IN2 : 1,
             IN3 : 1,
             ...;
} trigger_mask_fields_t;

typedef union {
    trigger_mask_fields_t fields;
    uint16_t bits;
} trigger_mask_t;
```

Currently I have no debugger for that chip.

Is that theory possible? if so, how can I solve it?

Comment: "I have no debugger for that chip" Then you can't develop programs for it, period.

Comment: @Lundin then arduino and most of  AVR & 8051 guys cannot develop is they do not have debuggers as well.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I'm waiting to get my debugger. but actually I asked that anyway because it's a good info to know, even if that is not the reason.

Comment: @Lundin: While interactive debuggers can often be nice, they're not essential, and there are many cases where they really don't work.  I don't know that I've ever used a chip whose debugger interacted well with low-power sleep modes.  While some chips have options to ensure that if a debugger's attached they won't go to sleep in such a fashion as to break the debugger connection, the chips I've seen that do that don't behave the same way in that mode as they would when normal sleep was enabled, making the debugger useless for diagnosing problems surrounding wake-up events.

Comment: Did you try to disable the interrupt before reading the mask, and re-enabling it after your critical part?

Comment: @thebusybee but then I may will miss out changes, no? Is it a better idea to read the inputs once on each loop without using the interrupt?

Comment: @0___________ Indeed, their choice of MCU suggests as much. But yes of course you can use icky serial output things, been there done that as well. UART-based bootloaders that came with very limited, poor man's debugger options. I had to endure such crap as late as ~ year 2005 even. Fortunately, technology has progressed since the middle ages and we don't have to resort to such completely outdated & primitives means. Nothing is _stopping_ you for driving a horse & wagon on the streets, to use a telegraph instead of smart phones, to use hand-written letters instead of the Internet. Go ahead.

Comment: @supercat You can perhaps debug such with clever tricks: write to a memory location first thing you do when waking up, then trigger a write breakpoint. Or read the instruction trace. Anyway I don't see how _not_ having a debugger would improve the situation...

Comment: @Lundin: The debuggers I've used can only maintain a connection to an ARM-based microcontroller as long as that microcontroller has an active clock.  If the microcontroller's clock stops, the debuggers will disconnect and cannot be reconnected without resetting everything.  While some microcontrollers offer a function to prevent the clock from being stopped when a debugger is attached, the controllers I've seen with that feature will continue to feed the clock not only to the debug circuitry, but also to anything else that it would operate, thus causing timers to keep running.

Comment: @Lundin: Incidentally, I've also found that some ARM-based microcontrollers seem to lock up if they try to do an `NVIC_SystemReset()` with a debugger attached.  Not sure of the exact failure mechanism but it causes problems anyway.  I would think it should be practical to construct an ARM-based micro in a fashion that would allow debugging to continue smoothly through low-power sleep and soft-reset scenarios, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: @supercat  `Incidentally, I've also found that some ARM-based microcontrollers seem to lock up if they try to do an NVIC_SystemReset()` - nonsense. I do ARM-Cortex uC programming as my daytime job and hobby for years and I never had this problem.  You can debug in low power modes and software resets without any problems.

Comment: @Lundin 'icky serial output things' lol yes, it's truly nasty and I end up spending as much time on the serial debug code as developing the 'real' software:(

Comment: @0___________: I know I have such problems with Segger's debugging tools using the SWD port.  Perhaps other tools work better?

Comment: I use jlink ultra as our main debug probe. No problems at all

Comment: Well, no. Disabling the interrupt simply delays the call of the ISR to the point when the interrupt is re-enabled. The pending interrupt will be handled in any case. Think what the difference is when the interrupt occurs 1) between these two instructions, or 2) after the second instruction. Why do you think you will miss out changes?

Comment: @supercat There's also Lauterbach, but they are expensive. Though I have good experience from using Segger - it's more important what PC software you hook it up to. Stay clear of anything based on Eclipse.

Comment: @thebusybee I thought about it and since I'm allways reading the current input value the only problem I can think about is when the interrupt turned on a bit in the mask right after copying it but before resetting it. I thought also to reset just the copied bits (mask &= ~copy), but I can check these things just on Sunday (when I will be in the office).

Comment: Correct, and in this case the temporary disable will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the interrupt before you read from the mask variable, and after clearing the mask, you will enable the interrupt again. You make this little block kind of "atomic" from the view of the interrupt.

This way an interrupt, which would be served during both statements, will be pending until the enable, and it will be served then. No interrupts are lost.

This is a very similar situation as if the interrupt occurs during the first or during the second statement. Often such a statement is compiled into multiple assembly instructions, and the interrupt can be served "in the middle" of the statement.

Such a delayed interrupt is very similar to an interrupt that is served right after the second statement.